# How can I configure my Ethernet connection when booting from Recovery HD?

Tags: network, recovery, ethernet

I'm trying to recover from a Time Machine drive sitting on the network at work. Our network doesn't use DHCP–it requires the Ethernet connection to be manually configured. I've looked at the Network Utility while booted to the Recovery HD and I have a 169.254.x.x IP address. Is there any way to manually configure the Ethernet connection?

Answer (score 1):

The expected graphical settings are not provided from the recovery image, but you can find terminal in the Utilities folder and use `ipconfig` to set a manual IP address and net mask for any active interface.

> ipconfig set en1 manual 192.168.3.1 255.255.255.0

As long as your Wi-Fi isn't connected, you should have a valid route, but you could also set a default `route` if needed using that command as well.

Answer (score 0):

I found an answer [in this blog post by maninara](http://maninara.blogspot.de/2015/08/setting-static-ip-address-in-os-x.html), referencing [this apple support document](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT200168). One can use the Terminal to perform this configuration:

1. Start Terminal from Utilities menu
2. `networksetup -listallnetworkservices` to see name of service
3. `networksetup -setmanual "‹service›" ‹address› ‹netmask› ‹router›`
4. `networksetup -setdnsservers "‹service›" ‹dns1› [‹dns2›…]`
5. `networksetup -getinfo "‹service›"` and `networksetup -getdnsservers "‹service›"` to verify configuration if you want to
6. Terminate Terminal application and launch a recovery option

Example (adapted from a Yosemite recovery session):

```
-bash-3.2# networksetup -listallnetworkservices
Ethernet
Wi-Fi
Thunderbold Bridge
-bash-3.2# networksetup -setmanual "Ethernet" 192.168.1.200 255.255.255.0 192.168.1.1
-bash-3.2# networksetup -setdnsservers "Ethernet" 192.168.1.1 192.168.1.25 8.8.8.8
-bash-3.2# networksetup -getinfo "Ethernet"
Manual Configuration
IP address: 192.168.1.200
Subnet mask: 255.255.255.0
Router: 192.168.1.1
IPv6: Automatic
IPv6 IP address: none
IPv6 Router: none
Ethernet Address: ab:cd:ef:12:34:56
-bash-3.2# networksetup -getdnsservers "Ethernet"
192.168.1.1
192.168.1.25
8.8.8.8
```