# Can I restore from a Time Machine backup without booting to the Recovery HD?

Tags: time-machine, recovery

At work we have a Time Machine drive on the network. I'm trying to restore one of our machine's backup to an external drive. When I boot into the Recovery HD, [I can't reach the network drive](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/87092/how-can-i-configure-my-ethernet-connection-when-booting-from-recovery-hd). Is there a way to restore a Time Machine backup without booting to the Recovery HD?

Answer (score 1):

You can restore from a Time machine backup with the Migration Assistant app. You can find it at /Applications/Utilities/

I have never used it with networked Time Machine drives.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I gave it a try but it only wants to restore to the internal drive. I need to restore to an external drive.

Comment: I'm not clear what you are trying to achieve, what do you mean by restore a machine's backup to an external drive? Are you trying to restore an entire machine state or just one file?

Comment: I'm trying to restore an entire machine state to an external drive. I think the drive in my co-worker's MBP is beginning to fail and I'd like to try booting from the external drive.